# Not able to fetch selected value from dropdown into a php variable, and use the value of that variable to fetch other data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a form that has some text fields and 2 drop-down lists, from the first drop-down list I need to fetch the selected value and store it in a PHP variable so I can use that variable to fetch another set of data into the 2nd drop-down. I do not want to use the submit button.
I have tried using ajax, I am getting the value as chosen in the console, but not able to fetch the same into a PHP variable.

```
//1st Drop-down
<dl>
  <dt>Project ID</dt>
  <dd> 
  <!-- Function to select the dropdown value -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo 
  url_for('/public/js/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          function fetch_select(val)
          {
             console.log(val);
             $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/flat_booking_again/adminsAccess.php",
               data: {
               get_option:val
               }, success: function(response){
                   console.log(response);
                   document.getElementById("new_select").innerHTML=response; 
                   //alert(get_option);
               }
            });
          }

          </script>    
          <select name = "project_id" style ="width:150px" onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
          <option>  
          <?php 
               $result = find_projects_without_admins();

               foreach($result as $row) { ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $row['project_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $row['project_id']; ?></option>
               <?php }?>

          </option>
          </select>        
          </dd>
          </dl>
      <dl>
      //I need to use the fetched data from above to populate this drop-down
      <dt>Block ID</dt>
      <dd>
      <select id="new_select" name="block_id" style ="width:150px"> 
      <option> 
      <?php
       echo $_POST['get_option'] . "hellllllllllllo"; //Not able to fetch value
        if(isset($_POST['get_option'])){
        $projectId = $_POST['get_option'];
        $result = find_blocks_without_admins($projectId);
        foreach($result as $row) { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $row['block_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $row['block_id']; ?></option>
           <?php }
        }
      ?>
      </option>
      </select>
```

I am really new to PHP and AJAX sp pardon me for any silly mistakes. I know this may sound like a repeated question, but I am stuck with this bug for long, any help is really appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: you need to clear out your basics with front-end script and backend (server side) scripts. Because as you said, you want to get dropdown value using JS and store it to php variable is not possible. PHP is server side script and JS is client side, so you can not have value of JS variable into php like this.

Comment: you are doing wrong here. in your success part of the Ajax , you need to create options for the select drop down and append those values in `new_select` drop down

Comment: where is your /flat_booking_again/adminsAccess.php please post the code of /flat_booking_again/adminsAccess.php

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay yes I do understand what you told. And I did not specify that I need to get the selected value using javascript. I told I tried to do so using ajax and javascript. And asked if there is any other better way to achieve this.

Comment: @RahulShrivastava I have this form in this php file itself.. the above dropdowns are part of the form I am using in this php file `/flat_booking_again/adminsAccess.php`

Comment: where is your query

Comment: and post the code of find_projects_without_admins()

Comment: @prakashtank if you don't mind could please elaborate a bit more

Comment: @RahulShrivastava The problem is not with that function. that function is where I query and return the data. the returning is happening, the drop-down is populating, but I am not able to fetch the selected value.

Comment: @hushie : first of all let us know what are you getting in response?

Comment: @prakashtank In the response i.e when I check the console I am getting the content of the whole page, instead of the whole page I just want the selected value.

Comment: @hushie : in this page `flat_booking_again/adminsAccess.php` just write your sql query and fetch the data and return to the ajax success after that append the data for ex: <option>Your data</option> like this.

Answer (score -1):

**Change your code with this.**

```
<dl>
  <dt>Project ID</dt>
  <dd> 
  <!-- Function to select the dropdown value -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo url_for('/public/js/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function fetch_select(val)
      {
          console.log(val);
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/flat_booking_again/adminsAccess.php",
            data: {
            get_option:val
            }, success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                document.getElementById("new_select").innerHTML=response; 
                //alert(get_option);
            }
        });
      }

      </script>    
    <select name = "project_id" style ="width:150px" onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
          <option>  
          <?php 
               $result = find_projects_without_admins();

               foreach($result as $row) { ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $row['project_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $row['project_id']; ?></option>
               <?php }?>

          </option>
          </select>        
          </dd>
    </dl>
      <dl>
      //I need to use the fetched data from above to populate this drop-down
      <dt>Block ID</dt>
      <dd>
      <select id="new_select" name="block_id" style ="width:150px"></select> 

      <?php
       //echo $_POST['get_option'] . "hellllllllllllo"; //Not able to fetch value
        if(isset($_POST['get_option'])){
          $projectId = $_POST['get_option'];
          $result = find_blocks_without_admins($projectId);
          $html = '';
          foreach($result as $row) { ?>
             $html.="<option value='".$row['block_id']."' selected='selected'>".$row['block_id']."</option>";
          }
          echo $html;
        }
      ?>
```

Comment: I get the form onClick of a button, so when I made the change you suggested that button turned into a link and the form is not getting displayed onClick.

Comment: You can make new page and give the url in the ajax and php code in that ajax files.

Comment: Is it not possible to do achieve what I am trying in the same page?

Comment: Yes it is possible with the same page